# extract and print string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

how can i extract a string like : '**peter_________Parker_____may**___   ' . and the output will be like: 'Peter_Parker_May'.

Comment: Please add more sample data along with your SQL code, if you have any.

Comment: i a newbie, so i dont have any code, srr

Comment: Explain in words what you are trying to accomplish.  My guess is that you want to replace 2 or more consecutive _ characters with a single _ character and then remove any trailing _ characters.  But that's a guess.  My guess is that the changes in capitalization between your input and output are unintentional.  Maybe you intend the _ in your sample data to represent an arbitrary character and you want to extract just the three substrings "peter", "parker", and "may" and capitalize the first letter in the output.

Comment: yes, the _ characters just stand for the 'space' characters and the output will remove any nesscesary 'space' character

Answer (score 1):

The following produces the requested output from the sample input in your question.

```sql
select initcap(trim(trailing '_'
                        from regexp_replace('peter_________Parker_____may___',
                                            '_+',
                                            '_'))) as RESULT
  from DUAL
```

- Function `regexp_replace` replaces all occurrences of one (or more) underscore characters with a single underscore character.
- Function `trim` removes trailing underscore characters.
- Function `initcap` capitalizes the first character in each word.

Refer to Oracle database documentation, namely [Character Functions Returning Character Values](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-06062705-1EC8-44ED-89B8-0F0573B74EA2) in *SQL Language Reference*

Also refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=cc18952514eb8775a4ba539b04e0a1e3)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to

- remove superfluous underlines
- remove trailing underline
- capitalize first letter

Then this might be one option:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'peter_________Parker_____may___' from dual)
  3  select initcap(rtrim(regexp_replace(col, '_+', '_'), '_')) result
  4  from test;

RESULT
----------------
Peter_Parker_May

SQL>
```